# marginal density problem

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $m(t)$ be a moment generating function of some random variable. Which of the following are Moment generating functions of some other random variables?

a. $m(t)m(6t)$

b. $-3m(t)$

c. $\mathrm{e}^{-t}m(t)$

d. All of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\xi$ such that $m(t) = Ee^{t \xi}$. Suppose that $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent and have the same distribution. Then m.g.f. of $\xi + 6 \eta$ is equal to
$$Ee^{t (\xi + 6 \eta)} = Ee^{t \xi}Ee^{6 t  \eta} = m(t) m(6t).$$
Also m.g.f. of $\xi - 1$ is equal to
$$Ee^{t (\xi -1)} = Ee^{t \xi} e^{-t}.$$
Any m.g.f. is equal to $1$ when it's parameter is equal to $0$. Thus a) and c) are m.g.f. and b) is not.